# Is there any platform-independent Lib to work with filesystem?

Tags: c++, cross-platform

Is there any open source Lib using which I can implement cross-platform working "Directory Listing" program (i.e the lib which works with file-system) and should work on (win, linux, solaris, mac 32 and 64 bit distributions)?
I have looked in boost, but couldn't find such thing. Maybe I wasn't enough attentive...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

boost has [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/filesystem/v2/doc/index.htm)

Answer (score 3):

I guess [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) is what you were looking for in boost.